# Very ample line bundle on a projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, line-bundles

This is an example in Hartshorne. $X$ is the nonsingular cubic curve $y^2z = x^3 - xz^2$ in $\mathbb{P}_k^2$, and $\mathscr{L} = \mathscr{L}(P_0)$, where $P_0$ is the point $(0,1,0)$. He claims that $\mathscr{L}$ is ample because $\mathscr{L}(3P_0) \cong \mathscr{O}_X(1)$, but I don't see how this isomorphism holds.

Comment: Hartshorne definitely does not claim that $\mathscr{L}(P_0)$ is very ample since that assertion is false..

Comment: I think what true is $\mathcal{L}(3P_0)$ is very ample. The curve $X$ has genus 1, so by IV3.2 (Hartshorne), a divisor $D$ is very ample if $deg D \geq 2g + 1 = 3$. In this case degree of $3P_0$ is 3.

Comment: I meant $\mathscr{L}(P_0)$ is ample. That's been fixed.

Comment: @user113988 that's a good point, so I guess $\mathscr{L}(3P)$ would be very ample for any point on the curve, right?

Comment: Yes I agree. And it then follows that $\mathscr{L} = \mathscr{L}(P)$ is ample for any point $P \in X$ since $\mathscr{L}^3$ is very ample.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is a section of $\mathcal O_X(1)$ such that the divisor of zeros of this section is $3P_0$ (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599467/restriction-of-weil-divisor-at-inflection-point/2601039#2601039)). Then use Exercise 14.2.E in Vakil's notes.